# google app engine if images not found set default images

Tags: google-app-engine

I follow the tutorial on the google app engine Using the images python API http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages.html, my question is that how do I modify the code

```
if greeting.avatar:
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
    self.response.out.write(greeting.avatar)
else:
    self.error(404)
```

instead of displaying error, how to I display a default image (static jpeg etc)?

Answer (score 2):

```
self.redirect("path/to/static/image")
```